# REST API not works

Tags: dspace

I'm working on a project and we're using dspace6 and I want to use the api rest. According to the documentation it is already present, but it needs to configure some things.

I made the settings but when access / rest is redirected to another port using SSL.

I've also disabled SSL but so far nothing.

Does anyone know how to install api rest on dspace 6?

Comment: Please read Stackoverflow's guidelines on how make a question in Stackoverflow.

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: It generally helps to include details on the actual settings you made. Links to the relevant parts of the documentation wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official documentation on installing the DSpace 6 REST API](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/REST+API#RESTAPI-InstallingtheRESTAPI), what you need to do is this:

> **Installing the REST API**
>
> The REST API deploys as a standard webapp for your servlet container / tomcat. For example, depending on how you deploy webapps, one way would be to alter tomcat-home/conf/server.xml and add:
>
> ```
> <Context path="/rest"  docBase="/dspace/webapps/rest" />
> ```
>
> In DSpace 4, the initial/official Jersey-based REST API was added to DSpace. > The DSpace 4 REST API provides READ-ONLY access to DSpace Objects.
>
> In DSpace 5, the REST API adds authentication, allows Creation, Update, and Delete to objects, can access restricted materials if authorized, and it requires SSL.
>
> **Disabling SSL**
>
> For localhost development purposes, SSL can add additional getting-started difficulty, so security can be disabled. To disable DSpace REST's requirement to require security/ssl, alter `[dspace]/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/web.xml` or `[dspace-source]/dspace-rest/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` and comment out the  block, and restart your servlet container. Production usages of the REST API should use SSL, as authentication credentials should not go over the internet unencrypted.

Which of these steps have you done? Did you restart your servlet container (eg tomcat)? Then what do you use to test the REST API, and what happens -- you need to show the actual URL you use and the response.